# Multi layer button / ring button

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to create custom button. This will be circle with rings, each ring is separate button. Button text will be displayed on rings. Bellow you can find image how button will looks.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/90/ringbutton.png

I would like to know if it is possible to create this kind of button using VS and WPF.

Do I need third party libraries? 
Any examples of similar buttons?

---

As I written before I had put different size circle buttons one over another and is working like dream. But still I can't display some text on created "rings".

I had use path to display text on rings but is complicated (for me) and text cover button so I can't click where text is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put the image on your form and implement a Click() event. It's really not that different from a "real" button.

Comment: I would add that you can simply layer your images on top of each other to create the look.  Also you can change the cursor to a Hand to to make it appear as more of a button to the user.

Comment: Thanks, I already did how you said guys and is working. Now I need add text on path to every ring. Any idea how to do that?